# I am little confused between class, object and instance

Tags: c#

I read a lot about difference between class,object and reference. 
But I have question in mind.So please help me in solving that.
Suppose

```
Class A        //declaration of class
{
//
}

main()
{
    A s1 = new A();
    A s2 = new A();
}
```

Now Question is that
In above code that how many there is different object and instance in the memory.?

If one says there is two different object and two instance (i.e s1 and s2)
then if we change in one instance suppose s1 then it also reflects changes in s2 also. Which shows that there is only one object present in the memory.

So How can we made different objects in the memory of same class A?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: "then if we change in one instance suppose s1 then it also reflects changes in s2 also" - I don't even think that statement is true actually.

Comment: Its true , @Caramiriel you can counter check in a code  because both s1 and s2 are pointing to same class A

Comment: No, they point to two different instances of class A. Thats something different. Hence the `new` keyword. Consider two marbles. They are both 'a' marble, but they're not the same marble. One may even have different colors.

Comment: so how can we make multiple instance of the same object.?if both are two different marble according to you.

Comment: I think the answers below did a great job on explaining it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code, there are 2 instances of class `A` in memory. `s1` and `s2` each point to a memory address where a `A` instance lives.

Using the words `object` and `instance` tend to mean the same thing, so you could use them interchangeably.

Now, if you did this:

```
main()
{
    A s1 = new A();
    A s2 = s1;
}
```

In that case, both `s1` and `s2` point to the same object/instance (same memory address). So if you made changes to either `s1` or `s2` then they would be reflected either way.

EDIT:

A little extra explanation...

```
main()
{
    A s1 = new A();  
}
```

In the above code, the variable `s1` is instantiated to a new `A` instance. Two things have happened here

- An instance of `A` has been created in the heap memory region.
- `s1` stores (on the stack) the memory address in the heap.

`s1` will be created on the stack, and it is effectively a pointer to the memory address in the heap where the `A` instance has been created.

Hopefully this extra bit of info is helping to clarify things.

EDIT:

You can create as many instances as the memory on your PC will allow.

```
main()
{
    A s1 = new A();
    A s2 = new A();
    A s3 = new A();
    // etc until you run out of memory.
}
```

I strongly suggest you look at buying some books to help you grasp the fundamentals of .NET programming. My favorite book, and one I turn to a lot, it [`CLR via C# 4th Edition`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454). You can't go wrong with that book.

Comment: Not to speak of the so called `System.Object` which is the superclass of all classes.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply But as i know that objects are stored in a heap and instance are stored in a stack inside a memory.and stack memory is lost as soon as scope is end. so according to you class object is lost as the scope is end

Comment: To clarify - objects and instances are the same thing. An instance is an object in memory (you're right in saying the heap). `objects` do not live on the stack. What would be on the stack is the memory address, in the heap, to an object instance. Try to forget about the term `object`, just think of `instance`, as that will be less confusing.

Comment: so who will save the address of the object(or you say instance) in the stack memory.is it instance only according to what i understand

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for this  help but can you please tell me that whether it is possible or not  to instantiated  more than once the same object or instance. Or if possible then please explain it with example.

Comment: Hi Jason now i have understand that we can made as many as instance of the same class type in our memory. But can i instantiated  same object more than once(i.e can we same address of same object/instance in more than one variable for example: both s1 and s2 reference variable  to the same instance of class A)

Comment: Take my last code example - if you then have  `A s2 = s1;` that means the variable `s2` now contains the same memory address for the instance stored in `s1`. Both `s1` and `s2` are pointing to the same instance.

Comment: thanks jason for all your help .now i am clear with my concept of object,instance and class..thanks alot again

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to your statement, "if we change in one instance suppose s1 then it also reflects changes in s2 also", the changes in s1 will *not* reflect in s2. Hence there *are* two instances in memory.

You could possibly be confused because a class can contain a property or field which is a reference to yet another object. Then you can perfectly reference the same object in both s1 and s2:

```
s1.s3 = new B();
s2.s3 = new B();
```

In that case of course, changing anything in `s1.s3` will reflect in `s2.s3`.

As for the title of your question, an Object is an Instance of a Class.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173110.aspx) website:

> An object is basically a block of memory that has been allocated and configured according to the blueprint. A program may create many objects of the same class. Objects are also called instances, and they can be stored in either a named variable or in an array or collection

Objects and instances are the same thing, and they belong to a class (are created from classes) by your code, you have created two objects in memory, and the variables `s1` and `s2` are references to these objects.

[image]

[Image Source](http://cocoate.com/book/what-object-oriented-programming)

Comment: Hi ojonugwa...so how can we made the exactly same object (for ex: exactly two similar ojonugwa) in our memory for the class boy.but we can made two or more different location in the memory(instances) that will point to same @ojonugwa